# How do I create a MySQL-style timestamp in Perl?

Tags: mysql, perl, cgi

I need to get my Perl script to come up with the same format as MySQLs timestamp field. Does anyone know how to do that?

That's really only the first step. What I need to do with the timestamp is add time on to it. For example, how do I add 1 week on to the timestamp so I know what the date is exactly 7 days from now?

I'm stuck! I hate working with time and this time it's worse because I've never had to add on to time before.

Comment: Don't do it in Perl, do it inside the database: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: There is a [DateTime::Format::MySQL](http://p3rl.org/DateTime::Format::MySQL).

Answer (score 1):

```
use DateTime::Format::MySQL qw( );

my $dt = DateTime::Format::MySQL->parse_datetime($mysql_ts);
$dt->add( days => 7 );
$mysql_ts = DateTime::Format::MySQL->format_datetime($dt);
```